# Hash Table insert

Tags: java, hash

I don't understand this code, to insert a new element to an array (hash table)
I understand that if it's empty, then we add the new element, and we return null (because before, the value was null).

But I don't understand  while `(e != null && !e.key.equals(c))`, it means that while it's not null and while the key is not equal to the one that we want to add? Isn't it supposed to be equal, since we use `indiHash(c)` to find the position in the array where we add the new element, so if there are in the same bucket they should have the same keys: and then we go to the next one, which means that we are going to add that element at the complete end of the bucket list? I also don't understand

```
valuebefore = e.valor;
e.valor = v;
```

What are we returning? The value of the element that was last on the bucket list before we added the new one?

I don't understand how can there be a `if (e != null)` because just before, in the while loop, we made sure that the `e` is null when we leave the loop

```
public V insert(C c, V v) {

    V valuebefore = null;
    int position = indiHash(c);
    EntryHash<C, V> e = Array[pos];

    while (e != null && !e.key.equals(c))
        e = e.next;

    if (e == null) { 
        Array[position] = new EntryHash<C,V>(c, v, Array[position]);
        size++;
    } else { // 
        valuebefore = e.valor;
        e.valor = v;
    }
    return valuebefore;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Many different objects can have the same hash code. And even if they don't have the same one, since the array has a length much shorter than 2^32 (the number of different possible hash codes), objects with different hash codes end up in the same bucket.

So objects which end up in the same bucket are stored in a linked list of entries. The above code tries to find an entry in this linked list that has a key equal to the inserted key. If it doesn't find any, a new entry is created and added to the linked list. Otherwise, the value associated with the found entry is replaced by the new value.

Comment: but what does while (e != null && !e.key.equals(c)), literally mean? while e is "empty" and c is different than the key of e it will look for the next element in the linkedlist? i would think that on that specific linkedlist they all have the same key because they all have the same hashcode and that's why they are in the same array

Comment: It literally means "continue to loop while e is not null and the key in e is different from c". Or, if you prefer, "stop looping as soon as e is null, or as soon as the key in e is equal to c". And no, what you think is wrong, as my answer explains. Imagine the keys are integers, and the size of the array is 15. 0 will have 0 as hashCode. 0 modulo 15 will be the bucket index. So it will go in bucket 0. 30 will have 30 as hashCode. 30 modulo 15 will be the bucket index. So it will also go in bucket 0, even though it doesn't have the same hashCode as 0, and is not equal to 0.

Comment: so  valuebefore = e.valor;
        e.valor = v; is executed in the case when e is not null and the key in e is equal to c ? and why they execute  e.valor = v? what s the point?

Comment: The point is to replace the old value by the new one. That's the whole point of the method: after you insert a value in the map, you want the value to be in the map.

Comment: but do we add it at the end of the linkedlist? and what is the point of returning the last value before we add the new one?

Comment: No. Just read the code. The new entry is added at the beginning of the linked list. The point of returning the old value is to respect the documented contract of the method: the calue returned by the method is the previous value associated with the given key, or null if the key didn't exist in the map.

Comment: but i thought that we do this e = e.next; so we get to the end of the linkedlist and add it there...

Comment: e = e.next goes to the next entry to test if the next entry contains the given key or is null. That's not where a new entry is created. The new entry is created in `Array[position] = new EntryHash<C,V>(c, v, Array[position]);`. And you thus see that the new entry is created and stored in the array, and that this new entry has the entry that was previously the first one as next node.

Comment: okay, so basically, we first find the right bucket: we copy on e what there is in that bucket: if it is empty then we add a new entry in the array at that position. if it's not empty, we use the while loop to search in this linked list but what i don't  understand is why can't we just add at the first position, and say that the next one=the one we're replacing?  can you make a little exemple ? because i'm not sure to understand why we're looking for something in that linked list that has the same key...

Comment: Because the map can only contain a given key once. The principle of a map is that a key is only stored once in the map. If we store a different value for the same key, then the new value must replace the old one, and the old value must be returned by the insert() method. That's how a map is supposed to work.

Comment: oh ok, so we just search with the while loop if there's not already in that linkedlist a map with the same key and if that's the case, we replace it and we return the old value?

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in my answer: *The above code tries to find an entry in this linked list that has a key equal to the inserted key. If it doesn't find any, a new entry is created and added to the linked list. Otherwise, the value associated with the found entry is replaced by the new value.*